# Firebug step-over doesn't break on next line

Tags: debugging, firebug, breakpoints

I'm trying to debug JavaScript in Firebug but have very little success so far. I've set up a few breakpoints on every few lines in a JavaScript in Firebug. The problem is that whatever **step buttons** I use it won't execute and stop at the next line. If I understand correctly this is the function of the **step over** button. Instead, what happens is is that whatever **step button** I click the script stops execution. The same happens if I click **Continue**, but if I click **Rerun** the script seems to execute to completion without stopping at later breakpoints.

I've been trying on and off during a few moths with different scripts and could never get it to step to the next line.

I tried using Chrome for this and there it works, but I'd rather work with Firebug as I'm more familiar with it.

I'm using Firefox 18.0 and Firebug 1.11.1 in OS X 10.8.2.

I feel frustrated from being unable to get it to work. Could somebody please help?

Example code:

```
<html>
     <body>
         <div>
         </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {

    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;

    $('div').append('<span>' + a + ' + ' + b + ' = ' + (a + b) + '</span>');
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4KgR/) example.

Comment: Is this a general problem? Or a problem with a particular piece of code? Can you post code that has this problem?

Comment: It seems to be a general problem. I added some example code. Maybe it's a problem with the Firebug settings or configuration files.

Comment: Maybe the issue is with your installation / profile. Try [setting up a new profile from scratch](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles).

Comment: I updated FF to 19.0 and made a new profile as you suggested and it now works. Maybe you could make your suggestion an answer.